# compilation error when trying to define a new python like pow operator

Tags: idris

I want to mimic the Python's infix operator `**` in Idris2:

```
(**) : Double -> Double -> Double
(**) x y = pow x y
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Couldn't parse declaration.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Might be conflicting with dependent pair syntax

Comment: how could I know that @michaelmesser? the compiler message is not as useful as to realise what's really happening there.

Comment: Not sure. Idris doesn't have the best error messages.

Comment: i use `(^)` ...